# Chain rule for ordinary derivative of function of two variables?

Tags: partial-derivative, chain-rule

How does this type of chain rule work?
I don't see how it makes sense.
f is a function of x and y.

df/dx = *d*f/*d*x + *d*f/*d*y * dy/dx

Normal "d" is ordinary derivative, italicized "d" is partial derivative.

Comment: do you mean $$F(x,y(x))$$?

Comment: Yes that is what I mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is called [total derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative) and it is just a **special case for the chain rule** with

$$f=f(t,x(t),y(t),...)$$

More precisely, total derivative is a special case of composition $f\circ g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R} $ with $f:\mathbb{R^n}\to\mathbb{R}$ and $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R^n}$.

In this particular case we have

$$f(x,y(x))\implies \frac{df}{dx}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{d x}$$

Comment: Thanks Gimusi, however, aren't the dx/dx and dy/dx supposed to be ordinary derivatives?

Comment: ops yes of course, just a typo, y is a function of x indeed

Comment: I change it only in the final step since the result is directlly from the general expression of chain rule with partial derivatives.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: @JohnA. You are welcome, it's a plesure for me! Bye

Answer (score 1):

if so then we get $$\frac{\partial F(x,y(x))}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial F(x,y(x))}{\partial y}\cdot\frac{dy(x)}{dx}$$
and this is the chain rule since $$y=y(x)$$

Comment: Yes, that is the formula, but why and how does this formula work?

Comment: this is the derivative of an implicit function